# Trying to put Image on right side of page, next to text on the left, using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to have a image on the right of a block of text, using flexbox.
Have tried to use `justify-self:flex-end` on the CSS for the image, however it is not working as intended.

HTML:

```
<div class="introduction">
    <li><h2>Text</h2></li>
    <li><h3></h3></li>
    <li><h2>Text</h2></li>
    <li><h3></h3></li>
    <li><h2>Text</h2></li>
    <li><h3></h3></li>
    <li><h2>Text</h2></li>
    <li><h3></h3></li>
    <li><h2>Text</h2></li>
    <li><h3></h3></li>
    <img src="picofme.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.introduction{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  padding:10px;
  list-style:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.introduction h2{
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: normal;
  color:#707070;
  
}
.introduction h3{
  background:#646CC5;
  padding:5px;
  margin:10px;
  width:300px;
  height:5px;
 
}
.introduction img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

[Image of site, the image should be filling the empty space on the right, but it is currently below the block of text. Black boxes are placeholders for the text, which are fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW4wm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<li>` needs to be wrapped inside a `<ol>` or `<ul>` tag , then flex can be what you need indeed.

Also `<h3></h3>` are supposed to be titles holding text, not a design element, `<li>` can have border instead.

possible example:

```css
.introduction {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  width:max-content;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center; 
  width: 300px;
}

.introduction h2 {
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #707070;
  border-bottom: solid 1.6rem #646CC5;
}

.introduction img {
  margin: auto 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="introduction">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>Text</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Text</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Text</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Text</h2>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/159">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the snippet you can use. Basically I just removed `flex-direction: column;` from `.introduction` and changed it for `flex-direction: row;` to display child elements in the row. Then I wrapped this strange text elements into another div. Here's the result.

```css
.introduction{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  padding:10px;
  list-style:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.introduction h2{
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: normal;
  color:#707070;
  
}
.introduction h3{
  background:#646CC5;
  padding:5px;
  margin:10px;
  width:300px;
  height:5px;
 
}
.introduction img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.text_div {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="introduction">
  <div class="text_div">
    <li><h2>Text</h2></li>
    <li><h3></h3></li>
    <li><h2>Text</h2></li>
    <li><h3></h3></li>
    <li><h2>Text</h2></li>
    <li><h3></h3></li>
    <li><h2>Text</h2></li>
    <li><h3></h3></li>
    <li><h2>Text</h2></li>
    <li><h3></h3></li>
  </div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```